# What is best way to normalize an URI to extract just the domain name?

Tags: c#, .net, uri

For example:

```
http://www.google.co.uk
www.google.co.uk
google.co.uk
```

will all be converted to:

```
google.co.uk
```

I would have liked to use the System.Uri class but this only seems to accept urls with a scheme.

Comment: Add a scheme then, if not already there.

Comment: So add the scheme and then normalise it back off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this code

```
var url = "";
if (! url.Contains("://"))
{
        Url = "http://" + url;
}

var result = new Uri(url).Host;
```

Comment: I want to ensure that both www.google.com and google.com are seen as the same too. It is to prevent duplicate website entries into my system. Is replacing www. with an empty string robust enough?

Answer (score 9):

### Extracting the domain name is easy

The [`UriBuilder` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder.aspx) normalises URLs and handles many edge cases like a missing scheme. This makes it easy to extract the domain name. For example, these all give you `www.google.co.uk`:

```
new UriBuilder("www.google.co.uk").Host
new UriBuilder("http://www.google.co.uk").Host
new UriBuilder("ftp://www.google.co.uk:21/some/path").Host
```

### ...but removing `www.` is hard

The problem seems easy, but it's not. You can't reliably remove subdomains like `www` because there's no real distinction. The domain *is* `www.google.co.uk`, including `www`. There's nothing special about `co.uk` that makes `google` part of the domain and `www` not part of it — it just happens that `co.uk` is managed by the registrar, and `google.co.uk` is managed by Google.

To give you an idea of the problem, here's an [*incomplete* list of domain suffixes](https://publicsuffix.org/list/) which includes nearly 7100 entries so far. Notably, which part is which isn't even consistent:

```
URL                     the domain you want
---------------------   -------------------
http://www.crews.aero   crews.aero
http://www.crew.aero    www.crew.aero
```

The best approach would be [what Google itself does for Chrome's omnibar](https://publicsuffix.org/learn/): fetch the [(incomplete) list of domain suffixes](https://publicsuffix.org/list/), cache it temporarily, and compare domain names against the list of domain suffixes. You can see the result for yourself: type "crews.aero" in the Chrome omnibar and it will be treated as a URL, or type "crew.aero" and it will be treated as a search.